# Installing Extensions via VSCode CLI while VS Code is running

Tags: command-line-interface, visual-studio-extensions

My team's extension uses the VS Code CLI to install extensions, and in the past, we only tried to install if VS Code isn't running. After doing some investigation, it seems that it's safe to use the CLI to install extensions when VS Code is running. I was wondering:

1. In the past, was this not the case?
2. If so, when was that change made (what VS Code version) that allowed extension installations via the CLI while VS Code is running?